# Increase row height of UITableView, Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have label in a cell, when I click on a cell I want to cell increases as much as the size of label. Currently my code resizes the cell to 240.

My label:

```
UILabel *cellLabel3 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];
[cellLabel3 setText:[Data objectAtIndex:self.expandedIndexPath.row]];
```

Code for cell height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath compare:self.expandedIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        return 240;
    }
    return 90.0;
}
```

Comment: Where is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.expandedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Question has answer already But still posting answer,

Calculate Height of Text from method

```
CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(kLabelWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX);
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font
               constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
               lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

And replace kLabelWidth with label width & font with your label font
and return `size.height`  from heightForRowAtIndexPath.